# Next js 13 Script tag won't render in the right position

Tags: reactjs, next.js, embed, next.js13

I am using the Next Js Script tag to embed a form from Convertkit into my project. The embed gets pulled in, and it works, I can subscribe and my email appears in the Convertkit Dashboard, everything works as expected.

However, the form does not render where I am trying to place it, which is in my about page, but rather, gets appended to the bottom of each screen, as it if was outside of the html document (outside of the parent div in my return statement, no background styling or anything takes effect). Sometimes its rendered at the top of the screen, over every other content.

You can check out the test project here: https://testfetchdata-uier.vercel.app/about

This is what my embed looks like:

```
 <div className="flex flex-row space-x-4">
      </div>
      <>
        <Script
          async
          data-uid="PROJECT_ID"
          src="https://MYPROJECT.ck.page/PROJECT_ID/index.js"
        ></Script>
      </>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to what might be happening?
Thanks a lot.